# How to input numbers into a vector until I press enter

Tags: arrays, c, memory, input, scanf

I want to have a versatile code for which I don't have to input the number of numbers.
Instead of doing something like this

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){

int n,a[100];
scanf("%d", &n);
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%d ", a[i]); }
```

Here I would first input n and then input n numbers in my array.

To give a more concrete example, I want to code the union and reunion of two sets. Instead of thinking of the number of elements of each sets, I would just enter them as I please without limiting to the "n" I mentioned above.

Is there any way in which I could skip inputting n? And how would I declare my array as to not lose memory.

Comment: Use `fgets` to get the whole line, then parse the string.

Comment: Could you give me an example of code? I'm a beginner and I haven't encounter fgets and I don't know what "parse the string" means

Comment: You'll need some sort of value in the input to distinguish between the two sets.  Perhaps use a space to separate individual members of a set, and then a comma to mark the start of the next set.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a pointer to a block of memory which you keep increasing in size each time you go get a new number:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
  {
  int *a = NULL;
  int n = 0;
  char str[10000];

  while(fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin) != NULL &&
        strlen(str) > 1)
    {
    n += 1;
    a = realloc(a, n * sizeof(int));
    a[n-1] = atoi(str);
    }

  for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i)
    printf("a[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i]);
  }
```

[OnlineGDB here](https://onlinegdb.com/rJx49UqAD)

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this is to use `fgets` to read a line, then use `sscanf` to parse that line.  Something like:

```
char buffer[2048];
int a[100], n;
if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin)) {
    n = 0;
    char *p = buffer;
    int len;
    while(n < 100 && sscanf("%d%n", &a[n], &len) > 0) {
        ++n;
        p += len; } }
```

You might also want to use malloc/realloc for the array `a` so that it can start small and grow as large as you need based on the input, but that is a different question (with many answers here).

Answer (score 0):

You need to grow your memory buffer dynamically.  Here's a method that reads the first array as space separated integers, and looks for a semi-colon in the input to tell when the second array starts:

```
/* Read two sets of integers */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void * xrealloc(void *buf, size_t nmemb, size_t size, void *iterator);

struct buffer {
        int *start;
        int *end;
        size_t cap;
};

void push(int c, struct buffer *);

int
main(void)
{
        int c;
        struct buffer a = {0};
        struct buffer b = {0};

        while( scanf("%d", &c) == 1 ){
                push(c, &a);
        }
        if( (c = getchar()) != ';' ){
                fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected input\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        while( scanf("%d", &c) == 1 ){
                push(c, &b);
        }
        printf("set a: ");
        for( int *p = a.start; p < a.end; p++ ){
                printf("%s%d", p > a.start ? ", " : "", *p);
        }
        printf("\nset b: ");
        for( int *p = b.start; p < b.end; p++ ){
                printf("%s%d", p > b.start ? ", " : "", *p);
        }
        putchar('\n');
        return 0;
}

void
push(int c, struct buffer *b)
{
        if( b->start == NULL || b->end >= b->start + b->cap ) {
                b->start = xrealloc(b->start, b->cap += BUFSIZ, 1, &b->end);
        }
        *b->end++ = c;
}

void *
xrealloc(void *buf, size_t num, size_t siz, void *endvp)
{
        void **endp = endvp;
        ptrdiff_t offset = buf && endp && *endp ? *endp - buf : 0;
        buf = realloc(buf, num * siz);
        if( buf == NULL ){
                perror("realloc");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if( endp != NULL ){
                *endp = buf + offset;
        }
        return buf;
}
```

A simple run looks like:

```
$ echo '1 3 5; 3 5 9 3 5' | ./a.out 
set a: 1, 3, 5
set b: 3, 5, 9, 3, 5
```